# Google Maps SearchBox suggestions doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, blazor

I am using the Google Maps to create a map and let users search for location normally, but I just cant get the suggestions dropdown to appear. All other Google Maps features I am using works fine. This is my Javascript code:

```
newItemMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(newItemMapDivId), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 15,
        draggable: true
    });

    var input = document.getElementById(newItemSearchBoxId);


    try {
        newSearchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    newItemMap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

The Searchbox, map and controls appears and work well. Except for when I type inside of the searchbox input, nothing happens. I am expecting the suggestions dropdown to appear. I have tried with changing Google Maps API version, different z-indices and moving around the input but the suggestion drop down just wont appear. And I cannot figure out why, any help appreciated! I have both places and Geocoding activated in my Google Cloud. I do not get any errors in the console. Main hosting technology is Blazor Server.

Comment: Why did you post only that part of your code when **obviously** as you mentioned it yourself, it might have to do with HTML and/or CSS? You must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you have the places API enabled for the account associated with your key?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was a problem with the z-index. The components I used had some script that were always putting itself on the highest z-index.